# Use a program with the bootstrap command in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to get the standard error of a ratio in Stata, and so I need to make `bootstrap` compute this little program. But then, when doing `bootstrap`, I get this error:

```
‘bob’ invalid name
an error occurred when bootstrap executed myratio
```

Here is the code:

```
capture program drop myratio
program define myratio, rclass
args bob
count if ‘bob’== 1
‘empl’ = r(N)
count if ‘bob’== 2
‘uempl’ = r(N)
return scalar ratio = ‘uempl’/‘empl’
end

bootstrap ratio = r(ratio), reps(5) : myratio statuslfs
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Your program is buggy.

The quotation marks look quite wrong. The example

```
   local foo = 42 
   di `foo'
```

shows use of single quotation marks which can be shown in Stata by

```
  di char(96) "  " char(39)
```

Lines like

```
 `empl' = r(N)
```

even when corrected for the error above suggest that you think you can assign to local macros that way. Not so; that's a very wild guess. Use syntax such as

```
 local empl = r(N)
```

Try this:

```
 program myratio, rclass
 args bob
 quietly { 
     count if `bob'== 1
     local empl = r(N)
     count if `bob'== 2
 } 
 return scalar ratio = r(N)/`empl'
 end
```

N.B. `reps(5)` is presumably just for debugging purposes.